# Going to JMM (Joint Mathematics Meetings) for Jobs without interview invitations?

Tags: mathematics, conference, job-search, interview

Is it worth it (about $1000) to go to the JMM without any in-advanced-scheduled interview invitations?

Comment: Related: [Is attending an academic conference beneficial if you are not presenting any paper? Does it reflect well in your CV?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38874/4140)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you really will not know until January 2 whether you have any interview requests.  In my past experience, only about half of the JMM interview lists have been determined by Christmas, and some are not determined until right before the meeting.

Some departments are willing to do Skype preliminary interviews instead of Joint Meetings preliminary interviews, but Skype interviews can be hard to schedule, and a department that has already talked to a number of excellent candidates at the Joint Meetings has little motivation to schedule such interviews.

You should be aware that, for many jobs, a JMM preliminary interview isn't worth much.  I have heard of departments interviewing as many as 80 people for 1 position at JMM, though 20-30 is probably the usual number, and a few departments prefer longer interviews with only 10 or so candidates.

Finally, essentially zero research universities interview at JMM, though some of the top liberal arts colleges do.  If you are not interested in positions where teaching plays at least as important a role as research (and for most of the positions interviewing a much more important role than research), don't bother.

Answer (score 5):

Are you going just for jobs? If you are there you should at least attend some of the talks, network with folks in your field, go to the poster session, get some free swag from the vendors....

But if your only goal is to get a job or develop connections for getting said job, you should at the very least find out if the people with whom you need to talk are going, and if they are, when and where you can meet with them, even informally. If you made zero plans and are just hoping to show up and see how things go, then you should forget it: it is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the JMM is a lot of fun, you can learn from all the talks and meet mathematicians in a lot of different areas! It's a great experience if you are not on the job market at all. If you are, it can be much more stressful.

It is *possible* that attending might be beneficial in your job search. I went to the JMM twice when my department was hiring and I was on the hiring committee. Each time, I e-mailed out of the blue a candidate who had applied for our position (and whose special session talk I had gone to without first introducing myself), and invited them out to lunch. In each case I was very impressed with the candidate and let the rest of the hiring committee know.

In the end it didn't make much of a difference; we did not end up hiring either candidate, and they ended up getting jobs which were at least comparable to the one we were offering. The real benefit of these meetings, both to me and them, was that we made friends with each other and learned something interesting about each other's research.

So, the bottom line is -- it might help you to attend, especially if you are already a strong candidate, but only a little bit and even that is kind of a longshot. But figure out lots of paper sessions you want to go to, and make plans to go for dinner or drinks with old friends if you can. If you go to the JMM specifically hoping to line up interviews, and without a full slate of other things you want to do there, you're unfortunately likely to be disappointed.